# python 2.7 not installed properly by anaconda

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda

I'm using Ubuntu Linux 18.04, have anaconda 3 loaded with python 3.7.3 installed.  I follow the instructions to create a new environment with python 2.7 installed and it fails.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
$ conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda
```

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

### Package Plan

environment location: ....../...../anaconda3/envs/py27

added / updated specs:
    - anaconda
    - python=2.7

but after all the install, when I activate this environment, and then get the info, it is pointing to python 3.7.3.

```
$ conda info

 active environment : py27
active env location : /home/myusername/anaconda3/envs/py27
        shell level : 2
   user config file : /home/myusername/.condarc
```

populated config files : /home/myusername/.condarc

```
conda version : 4.7.10
conda-build version : 3.18.5
     python version : 3.7.3.final.0





   virtual packages : __cuda=9.1
   base environment : /home/myusername/anaconda3  (writable)
       channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
      package cache : /home/myusername/anaconda3/pkgs
                      /home/myusername/.conda/pkgs
   envs directories : /home/myusername/anaconda3/envs
                      /home/myusername/.conda/envs
           platform : linux-64
         user-agent : conda/4.7.10 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.3 Linux/4.15.0-55-generic ubuntu/18.04.2 glibc/2.27
            UID:GID : 1000:1000
         netrc file : None
       offline mode : False
```

Comment: Why do you include the `anaconda` package? That's a huge set of dependencies and I think unnecessary in 99% of envs. Really should only be installed in **base**.

Comment: "*it is pointing to python 3.7.3*" What's the evidence for this? The `conda info` output (`python version : 3.7.3.final.0`) always points to the Python in **base**. What does `python --version` say after activating?